# Not able to access pod swift file, after installing pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have created a pod using the raywenderlich tutroial [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift), everything works fine

creating

installing and

importing the pod too 

but when I am trying to access the view controller its says

`use of unresolved identifier 'file name'`

I tried cmd+click to jump to defination of the file and it navigating me to the file also

code implemented

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: SDKSplashVC.self) // error here - Use of unresolved identifier 'SDKSplashVC'
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SDKSplash", bundle: myBundle)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SDKSplashVC")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have imported the pod, crossed check in managed scheme and build phases, my custom pod is listed their but still error persist

Any help would be really helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code how you define `SDKSplashVC` in your pod

Comment: @Leo SDKSplashVC is normal view controller with just viewDidLoad func()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial author is using class `PickFlavorViewController` which is defined in `RWPickFlavor` cocoa pod.

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: PickFlavorViewController.self)
```

You can take a look and see all the files in this pod [here](https://github.com/jawwad/RWPickFlavor/tree/master/RWPickFlavor).

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) say that you can use the `init(for:)` initializer of `Bundle` to locate the framework bundle based on a class defined in that framework.

You are getting the error because `SDKSplashVC` is not defined. You need to write something like this:

```
import UIKit

public class SDKSplashVC: UIViewController {}
```

Make sure the class is defined as `public`.

Comment: I was missing the public access specifier, Thanks @Leo